# Exercise 4.9, Chapter I, in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Let $X$ be a projective variety of dimension $r$ in $\mathbf{P}^n$ with $n\geq r+2$. Show that for suitable choice of $P\notin X$, and a linear $\mathbf{P}^{n-1}\subseteq \mathbf{P}^n$, the projection from $P$ to $\mathbf{P}^{n-1}$ induces a birational morphism of $X$ onto its image $X'\subseteq \mathbf{P}^{n-1}$.

My way: W.L.O.G., assume that $X\setminus U_0\neq\emptyset$. Since $X$ is a projective variety, then $K(X)\cong S(X)_{(0)}$, which implies that $K(X)=k(x_1/x_0,\dots,x_n/x_0)$. Since $\dim X=r$, by Theorem 4.8A and Theorem 4.7A on page 27 in Hartshorne, then W.L.O.G., we can assume that $x_1/x_0,\dots,x_r/x_0$ is a separating transcendence base for $K(X)$ over $k$, which implies that $x_{r+1}/x_0,\dots,x_{n}/x_0$ are separable over $k(x_1/x_0,\dots,x_r/x_0)$. By Theorem 4.6A on page 27 in Hartshorne, $K(X)=k(x_1/x_0,\dots,x_r/x_0)[y]$, where $y$ is a $k(x_1/x_0,\dots,x_r/x_0)$-linear combination of $x_{r+1}/x_0,\dots,x_n/x_0$. Now I do not how to continue.

Comment: Now let $P = [0 : 0 : \cdots : 1]$. The projection $\pi$ away from $P$ is given by the rational map $$[x_0 : x_1 : \cdots : x_{n-1} : x_n] \longmapsto [x_0 : x_1 : \cdots : x_n]$$ which induces an inclusion of function fields $K(X') \hookrightarrow K(X)$, where $X'$ is the image of $X$ under the projection. $K(X') \hookrightarrow K(X)$ is actually an equality of fields since $x_1/x_0,\ldots,x_r/x_0,y \in K(X')$, and so $\pi$ is birational.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Do you mean $[x_0:x_1:\cdots:x_{n-1}:x_n]\mapsto[x_1:\cdots:x_n]$, or others? Thanks. What's the hyperplane? $Z(x_{r+1})$ ?

Comment: I think the projection should map to $[x_0:\cdots:x_{n-1}]$; apologies for the typo. The hyperplane projected to is indeed $Z(x_{n+1})$.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama I am confused about $Z(x_{n+1})$. Do you mean $Z(x_{r+1})$? In this case, maybe we should change $P$ to $e_{r+1}=[0,\cdots,1,\cdots,0]$. Also where do we use the condition $n\geq r+2$?

Answer (score 6):

I have rewritten this answer. We actually need a stronger version of Hartshorne's Theorem 4.6A (the theorem of the primitive element).

**Theorem 4.6A$^\star$.** *Let $L$ be a finite separable extension field of a field $K$, and suppose that $K$ contains an infinite subset $S$. Then, there is an element $\alpha \in L$ which generates $L$ as an extension field of $K$. Furthermore, if $\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_n$ is any set of generators of $L$ over $K$, then $\alpha$ can be taken to be a linnear combination*
$$\alpha = c_1\beta_1 + c_2\beta_2 + \cdots + c_n\beta_n$$
*of the $\beta_i$ with coefficients $c_i \in S$.*

*Proof.* This follows from the proof of [[Zariski–Samuel](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=384768), Ch. II, §9, Thm. 19], which uses Kronecker's "method of indeterminates," but we rewrite their proof below.

Consider the field extension
$$L \subseteq L(X,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$$
of $L$, where $X,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are a set of indeterminates, and consider the subfields
\begin{align*}
  K^\star &= K(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)\\
  L^\star &= L(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)
\end{align*}
in $L(X,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$. Then, $L^\star = K^\star(\beta_1,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n)$, and $L^\star$ is a finite separable extension of $K^\star$ since the $\beta_i$ are separable over $K$, and hence also separable over $K^\star$ (see [[Zariski–Samuel](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=384768), Ch. II, §5, Lem. 2]). Consider the element
$$\beta^\star = X_1\beta_1 + X_2\beta_2 + \cdots + X_n\beta_n \in L^\star.\tag{1}\label{eq:zs1}$$
Let $F(X)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\beta^\star$ in $K^\star[X]$. The coefficients of $F(X)$ are rational functions of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ with coefficients in $K$; let $g(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) \in K[X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n]$ be a common denominator of these rational functions. Then,
$$g(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) \cdot F(X) = f(X,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) \in K[X,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n],$$
and we have
$$f(\beta^\star,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) = 0.\tag{2}\label{eq:zs2}$$
Let
$$G(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) = f(X_1\beta_1+X_2\beta_2+\cdots+X_n\beta_n,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n).\tag{3}\label{eq:zs3}$$
Then, $G(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ is a polynomial in $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ with coefficients in $L$, and \eqref{eq:zs2} says $G(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) = 0$. Thus, all partial derivatives $\partial G/\partial X_i$ are zero for $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. By \eqref{eq:zs3}, we then have
$$\beta_i \cdot f'(\beta^\star,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) + f_i(\beta^*,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) = 0\tag{4}\label{eq:zs4}$$
for every $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, where
\begin{align*}
  f'(X,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) &= \frac{\partial f(X,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)}{\partial X},\\
  f_i(X,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) &= \frac{\partial f(X,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)}{\partial X_i}.
\end{align*}
The left-hand side in each equation \eqref{eq:zs4} is a polynomial in $L[X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n]$ by \eqref{eq:zs1}, and hence is the zero polynomial. Thus, the equations \eqref{eq:zs4} remain valid if we substitute for $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ any elements of $K$. On the other hand, we have
$$f'(X,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) = g(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)\,F'(X)$$
where $F'(X) = dF/dX$, and hence
$$f'(\beta^\star,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) \ne 0,$$
since $\beta^\star$ is separable over $K^\star$ and therefore $F'(\beta^\star) \ne 0$. Thus, $f'(\beta^\star,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ is a nonzero polynomial in $L[X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n]$. Since $S \subseteq L$ and $S$ is an *infinite* subset, we can find elements $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n \in S$ such that $(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n)$ is not a zero of that polynomial [[Zariski–Samuel](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=384768), Ch. I, §18, Thm. 14]. Setting
$$\beta = c_1\beta_1 + c_2\beta_2 + \cdots + c_n\beta_n,$$
we have that
$$f'(\beta,c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n) \ne 0\tag{5}\label{eq:zs5}$$
and
$$\beta_i \, f'(\beta,c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n) + f_i(\beta,c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n) = 0\tag{6}\label{eq:zs6}$$
for every $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. The equation \eqref{eq:zs6} and the inequality \eqref{eq:zs5} imply that $\beta_i \in K(\beta)$, and since $\beta \in L$, we therefore see that $L = K(\beta)$. This completes the proof of the theorem. $\blacksquare$

We now prove Hartshorne's exercise, which we restate below.

**Exercise** [[Hartshorne](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3849-0), Ch. I, Exer. 4.9]**.** *Let $X$ be a projective variety of dimension $r$ in $\mathbf{P}^n$, with $n\geq r+2$. Show that for a suitable choice of $P \notin X$, and a linear $\mathbf{P}^{n-1} \subseteq \mathbf{P}^n$, the projection from $P$ to $\mathbf{P}^{n-1}$ induces a* birational *morphism of $X$ onto its image $X' \subseteq \mathbf{P}^{n-1}$.*

*Proof.* Let $k$ denote the ground field over which $X$ is defined. After permuting coordinates, we may assume without loss of generality that $X\cap U_0\neq\emptyset$. Then, the images of the rational functions $x_i/x_0$ generate $K(X)$ over $k$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, we see the extension $K(X)/k$ is separably generated by [[Hartshorne](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3849-0), Ch. I, Thm. 4.8A]. Since $\dim X = r$, after possible permutation of coordinates, we have that $x_1/x_0,x_2/x_0,\ldots,x_r/x_0$ form a separating transcendence basis for $K(X)$ over $k$ by [[Hartshorne](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3849-0), Ch. I, Thm. 4.7A] to give the chain
$$k \subseteq k(x_1/x_0,x_2/x_0,\ldots,x_r/x_0) \subseteq K(X)$$
of field extensions.

Next, by setting $S = k$ in the theorem of the primitive element (Theorem 4.6A$^\star$ above), we see that $K(X)$ is generated by
$$\alpha = \sum_{i=r+1}^n c_i\frac{x_i}{x_0}$$
where $c_i \in k$ for every $i$. After a linear change of coordinates, we may assume that $\alpha = x_{r+1}/x_0$.

Now consider the map
\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{P}^n &\dashrightarrow \mathbf{P}^n\\
  [x_0:\cdots:x_{n-1}:x_n] &\mapsto [x_0:\cdots:x_{n-1}:0]
\end{align*}
This is the projection away from the point $P = Z(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$ to the hyperplane $Z(x_n)$. Restricting the codomain to $Z(x_n) \simeq \mathbf{P}^{n-1}$, we obtain the rational map
\begin{align*}
  \pi\colon \mathbf{P}^n &\dashrightarrow \mathbf{P}^{n-1}\\
  [x_0:\cdots:x_{n-1}:x_n] &\mapsto [x_0:\cdots:x_{n-1}]
\end{align*}
which we claim induces a birational map $\pi\rvert_X\colon X \dashrightarrow \pi(X)$.

Let $X'$ denote the image of $X$ through this map $\pi$. Then, $K(X')$ is generated by the rational functions $x_i/x_0$ for $1 \le i \le r+1$. The map on function fields corresponding to $\pi$ is
\begin{align*}
  K(X') &\hookrightarrow K(X)\\
  x_i/x_0 &\mapsto x_i/x_0
\end{align*}
Since $x_i/x_0$ for $1 \le i \le r+1$ generate $K(X)$, we see that $K(X') = K(X)$, and so the map $\pi$ is birational. $\blacksquare$

We note that to prove Exercise 3.14 with this method, we can perform the operation above $n - (r+1)$ times to find a birational map between $X$ and a hypersurface in $\mathbf{P}^{r+1}$. In the notation of the proof above, composing all of these projections from points can be described as the linear projection
\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{P}^n &\dashrightarrow \mathbf{P}^n\\
  [x_0:\cdots:x_n] &\mapsto [x_0:\cdots:x_{r+1}:0:0\cdots:0]
\end{align*}
away from the $(n-r-1)$-plane $Z(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{r+1})$ to the $(r+1)$-plane $Z(x_{r+2},x_{r+3},\ldots,x_n)$; see for example [[Shafarevich](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-37956-7), Ex. 1.27]. Restricting the codomain to the $(r+1)$-plane $Z(x_{r+2},x_{r+3},\ldots,x_n) \simeq \mathbf{P}^{r+1}$, this gives a rational map $\pi\rvert_X\colon X \dashrightarrow \mathbf{P}^{r+1}$ that is birational onto its image.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! Yet could you explain more on which point $P$ and plane $Sigma$ you chose to make the projection? Since in the exercise, it is required to project to some $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, I hope to make sure if you chose this demanding plane as plane $Z(x_j)$ for any $j=r+2, ... n$? Sorry for commenting on such an old post.

Comment: To be more explicit, I don't know how to understand the sentence "This is the projection away from the $(n-r-1)$-plane $Z(x_1/x_0,\ldots,x_r/x_0,\alpha)$ to the plane $Z(x_{r+2}/x_0,\ldots,x_{n}/x_0)$." So sorry for commenting on such an old post. Thank you for your excellent answer!

Comment: Dear @HetongXu, Thank you for the nice comments! I had to correct the answer a bit using the extra strength of the statement of the theorem of the primitive element in Hartshorne, but I hope this might make things a little clearer. In the notation of the proof, the projection $\pi$ can be described by projecting away from the point $Z(X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1})$ to the hyperplane $Z(X_n)$, then $Z(X_0,\ldots,X_{n-2})$ to the hyperplane $Z(X_{n-1})$, etc., until you finally project away from $Z(X_0,\ldots,X_{r+1})$ to the hyperplane $Z(X_{r+2})$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, now I can understand what Hartshorne means in the remark of this question! With your comments, it seems that we can get another proof of the Proposition I.4.9, which seems difficult to prove regarding the similar method of Exercise 11.23 of Joe Harris’s *Algebraic Geometry - A First Course*. Thank you so much your your great answers! Yet I’d like to ask a little bit more on this, i.e. can your description of the projection $\pi$ be reformulated as a projection from a **single point** to a plane? It seems difficult to do this.

Comment: And by reading the post, I think it is a doubt whether we can really find a SINGLE point and a HYPERplane to do the projection or not, which Hartshorne required us to do in the exercise.

Comment: Dear @HetongXu, I worked through the exercise again and hopefully it is a bit clearer (the point is that the proof of the theorem of the primitive element gives something stronger than what Hartshorne states; this resolves [this comment of Javier Linares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396576/on-an-exercise-from-hartshones-algebraic-geometry-ch-i-sect-4#comment6270109_396576) from a related question, I believe).

Comment: I should add that I have not yet shown that $P \notin X$; maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: Thank you for your update, it has become much clearer! Sorry for the late reply! I tried a lot on how to change the point or taking affine charts at the same time without loss of generality. Yet failed once again. I was inspired by another solution quoted in the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774090/hartshornes-exercise-i-4-9-what-is-the-desired-projection-explicity, which I raised serveral days ago.

Comment: ...... Going back to your great answers here, it seems that the key point is the condition on the dimension of $X$, i.e. $r \leq n-2$. I went through your updated solution yet haven't figure out where you used this condition. However, we may not embed the variety $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n-2}$ by just knowing the dimension condition. (For example, the twisted cubic curve.) So maybe here is the key trouble.

Comment: ...... For once we can embed this variety in $\mathbb{P}^{n-2}$, then we can both assume **WLOG** that the point $P$ is not in $X$ and at the same time assume that $X \cap U_0 \neq \emptyset$. Then we are done.