Problem 6.43 in Fulton's Algebraic Curves
I'm reading Fulton's Algebraic Curves (available here on the author's website), and I have some questions about the following problem.

6.43. Let $C$ be a projective curve, $P\in C$. Then there is a birational morphism $f:C\to C'$, $C'$ a projective plane curve, such that $f^{-1}(f(P))=\{P\}$.

Fulton gives some hints:
(a) We can assume $C\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$. Let $T,X_1,\cdots,X_n,Z$ be coordinates for $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$; then $C\cap V(T)$ is finite; $C\cap V(T,Z)=\varnothing$; $P=[0:\cdots:0:1]$; and $k(C)$ is algebraic over $k(u)$, where $u=\overline{T}/\overline{Z}\in k(C)$.
(b) For each $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)\in k^n$, let $\varphi_\lambda:C\to\mathbb{P}^2$ be defined by the formula $\varphi([t:x_1:\cdots:x_n:z])=[t:\sum\lambda_ix_i:z]$. Then $\varphi_\lambda$ is a well-defined morphism, and $\varphi_\lambda(P)=[0:0:1]$. Let $C'$ be the closure of $\varphi_\lambda(C)$.
(c) The variable $\lambda$ can be chosen so $\varphi_\lambda$ is a birational morphism from $C$ to $C'$ and $\varphi_\lambda^{-1}([0:0:1])=\{P\}$. (Use Problem 6.32 and the fact that $C\cap V(T)$ is finite).
Problem 6.32: Let $L=K(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ be a finite algebraic extension of $K$. Suppose $k\subseteq K$ is an algebraically closed subfield, and $V\subsetneq\mathbb{A}^n(k)$ is an algebraic set. Show that $L=K(\sum\lambda_ix_i)$ for some $(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)\in\mathbb{A}^n\setminus V$.
My question is about hint (3), how to choose $\lambda$, and how to use Problem 6.32?

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774090/hartshornes-exercise-i-4-9-what-is-the-desired-projection-explicity/3881392#3881392 . I'll write an answer here explaining the extra bits (namely, why we can assume nothing else gets mapped to the same place as $P$) soon.
